# How to find the regex to perform exact match in shell scripting

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have output from the kubernetes command

```
kubectl get pods | grep eam-ui
eam-ui-hk8rk                       1/1     Running            0          43m
eam-ui-jn9jj                       1/1     Running            0          43m
eam-ui-v02-2vdlh                   1/1     Running            0          2d6h
eam-ui-v02-4gkxx                   1/1     Running            0          2d6h
eam-ui-v03-2hqjq                   1/1     Running            0          2d22h
eam-ui-v03-jv4w7                   1/1     Running            0          2d22h
```

I need match the exact string from first column like ( eam-ui, eam-ui-v02, eam-ui-v03 ). The last 5 alphanumeric will change for each execution

Tried with -w and even with -F option. Works with v02 & v03 it Worked. But for eam-ui, it matching all

```
   $ kubectl get pods | grep -w eam-ui-v02
 eam-ui-v02-2vdlh                   1/1     Running            0          2d6h
 eam-ui-v02-4gkxx                   1/1     Running            0          2d6h

 kubectl get pods | grep -w eam-ui-v03


 eam-ui-v03-2hqjq                   1/1     Running            0          2d22h
 eam-ui-v03-jv4w7                   1/1     Running            0          2d22h
    
    
get pods | grep -w eam-ui
eam-ui-hk8rk                       1/1     Running            0          48m
eam-ui-jn9jj                       1/1     Running            0          48m
eam-ui-v02-2vdlh                   1/1     Running            0          2d6h
eam-ui-v02-4gkxx                   1/1     Running            0          2d6h
eam-ui-v03-2hqjq                   1/1     Running            0          2d22h
eam-ui-v03-jv4w7                   1/1     Running            0          2d22h
```

from above i wanted only

```
eam-ui-hk8rk                       1/1     Running            0          48m
eam-ui-jn9jj                       1/1     Running            0          48m
```

Comment: `grep -E '(eam-ui-[^-]+\s)'`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `awk` since you only need to check the first field values:

```
# To check eam-ui
kubectl get pods | awk '$1 ~ /^eam-ui-[[:alnum:]]{5}$/'

# To check eam-ui-v02
kubectl get pods | awk '$1 ~ /^eam-ui-v02-[[:alnum:]]{5}$/'

# To check eam-ui-v03
kubectl get pods | awk '$1 ~ /^eam-ui-v03-[[:alnum:]]{5}$/'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `eam-ui-` - literal text
- `[[:alnum:]]{5}` - five alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

See [online demo](https://ideone.com/UMA4WE)

Answer (score 0):

This will exclude lines containing v02 or v03:
`grep -v -e 'v0[2|3]' test.txt`